# Spark's df.saveAsParquetFile outputs extra files suffixed with _$file$ on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, amazon-emr, parquet

I'm converting csv.gz files to Parquet using Spark 1.3.1. The second field of my dataset contains timestamp of form:

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
```

For the output, each MM-dd, has its own folder / partition within our AWS S3 bucket.

```
val textFile = sc.textFile(<S3 path containing csv.gz files>)

val grouped = textFile.map({ row =>

    val cols = row.split(",")

    (cols(1).substring(5, 10), row)

}).groupByKey
```

`grouped` becomes an RDD of [String, Iterable[String]], 
an example of an entry looks like this :

```
"08-15", CompactBuffer(rowStr_1, rowStr_2, ..., rowStr_n)
```

The next step is to make the Iterable of each key as RDDs and then write as Parquet

```
val groupedRDD = grouped.collect

groupedRDD.foreach ({ group =>

    val rdd = sc.parallelize(group._2.toSeq)

    // group._1 is MM-dd
    rdd.toDF().saveAsParquetFile(<s3_bucket + parquet_folder> + group._1)

})
```

I've tested this in my machine's HDFS and it worked OK. When I tried to use it on AWS S3, the folders are generated with their Parquet files, however there are zero-byte files written as well of format

```
MM-dd_$folder$
```

so that it looks like the partitions have duplicates, like this:

```
08-15
08-15_$folder$
08-16
08-16_$folder$
.
.
.
```

When I use the alternative,

```
rdd.toDF().save(<s3_bucket + parquet_folder> + group._1, "parquet")
```

the result is the same.

In Spark 1.4.0 above, this should be

```
rdd.toDF().write.parquet(<hdfs or s3 path>)
```

which I cannot test if it will work in AWS S3 because our current EMR cluster is restricted to version 1.3.1

Can someone answer why is Spark doing this in S3?

Comment: This is a side effect of older compatibility of indicating a folder in S3 for Hadoop FS. Is this causing an issue with the processing or is it just a characteristic you noticed?

Comment: Also Spark 1.5.0 is available on EMR release 4.1.0.